# QuickBooks SDK - response.StatusMessage shows only the 1st error occured

Tags: c#, sdk, error-handling, quickbooks

I am using the QuickBooks SDK in C# .NET to add /edit vendors in my QuickBooks. When I make a request with multiple errors, say like passing more than allowed number of characters for both Name field and Address1 field, QuickBooks always returns only the first error. It does not return all the errors that I make. How to return all the errors?

The status message says I am tryin to enter more than the allowed no of characters for the Name field, but doesn't mention anything about the Address field for which I am also passing more than allowed no of characters. If I pass a proper value for Name and make a error in Address1 field, then it gives me error in that field.

I want to get all the errors at one go. How can I get it?

I am looping through the ResponseList and displaying the error but the ResponseList.Count is also always 1. What is the way to get errors in all the fields that I am passing in a single request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to return all the errors?

You can't. QuickBooks itself does not support this - it always just returns the first error it runs into.

The allowed values, data lengths, and data types are very well defined in the XSDs/OSR. You should be able to easily build some validation into your own application to catch these errors/enforce correct data entry *before* submitting the data to QuickBooks.

> I want to get all the errors at one go. How can I get it?
>   What is the way to get errors in all the fields that I am passing in a single request?

You can't. QuickBooks doesn't support this.